# Unique \nomlabelwidth for each \nomgroup with nomencl package

Tags: nomenclature, nomencl

in my thesis I use the `nomencl` package with different groups.
Since a few entries in one group are fairly long, I'd like to specifically increase the `\nomlabelwidth` in this `\nomgroup`.
Globally increasing the `\nomlabelwidth` would result in a lot of unnecessary white space in all other groups which I'd like to avoid.

Is is possible to `\setlength{\nomlabelwidth}{<value>}` within a group and not just globally?

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\setlength{\nomlabelwidth}{3em}

\renewcommand{\nomgroup}[1]{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{D}}{\item[\textbf{General notation}]}{%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{A}}{\item[\textbf{Acronyms}]}{}}
    \vspace{1.5em}% add space between groups
}

\begin{document}
Test nomenclature.
\nomenclature[D]{$\{\boldmath{e}_z,\boldmath{e}_y,\boldmath{e}_z\}$ or $\{\boldmath{e}_1,\boldmath{e}_2,\boldmath{e}_3\}$}{a long entry}
\nomenclature[D]{$\{\boldmath{E}\}$}{a short entry}
\nomenclature[A]{ADA}{a dummy acronym }

\printnomenclature

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of MWE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the required output you can start a new list within your `\nomgroup` command and set the relevant dimensions there, among which `\labelwidth` that controls the label width. Other relevant dimensions are `\leftmargin` and `\itemsep`. The left margin is the new label width minus the old label width. This code is largely taken from the source of the `nomencl` package, specifically the part where the `nomenclature` environment is defined (around line 250 in `nomencl.sty`).

Furthermore you should reverse the extra space that the new list generates using a negative `\vspace`. All in all it is a bit messy but it seems to work :)

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\setlength{\nomlabelwidth}{3em}
\renewcommand{\nomgroup}[1]{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{D}}{%
    \endlist%
    \list{}{%
      \labelwidth15em
      \leftmargin12em
      \itemsep\nomitemsep
      \let\makelabel\nomlabel}%
    \vspace{-1.5em}%
    \item[\textbf{General notation}]}{%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{A}}{\item[\textbf{Acronyms}]}{}}
    \vspace{1.5em}% add space between groups
}

\begin{document}
Test nomenclature.
\nomenclature[D]{$\{\mathbf{e}_z,\mathbf{e}_y,\mathbf{e}_z\}$ or $\{\mathbf{e}_1,\mathbf{e}_2,\mathbf{e}_3\}$}{a long entry}
\nomenclature[D]{$\{\mathbf{E}\}$}{a short entry}
\nomenclature[A]{ADA}{a dummy acronym }

\printnomenclature

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: That's great! Thank you very much!